# Creating SubDomain using .net API in Godaddy

Tags: asp.net

I wanna know that is there a way of creating subdomian in Godaddy domain using .NET API .?
any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question because there shouldn't be any issue with `foo.domain.com`, `bar.domain.com` being ASP.Net applications - so from the tags you have, the answer is a simple YES. If you're asking how to _setup subdomains in GoDaddy_ then that's clearly a GoDaddy Support question.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible according to https://developer.godaddy.com/doc, try to ask GoDaddy support team.

Answer (score 3):

URL: https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/YourDomainNameGoesHere/records

```
headers: 
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: 'sso-key key:secret },

body:
[ { type: 'A', name: 'subdomain_name', data: 'machine_id', ttl: 3600 } ] }
```

method: PATCH

For more deatils : [Godaddy API Documentation](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc#!/_v1_domains/recordAdd)

Comment: i'm trying to use the above code, but i get this response `{ code: 'INVALID_BODY',
  fields:
   [ { code: 'UNEXPECTED_TYPE',
       message: 'is not a array',
       path: 'records' } ],
  message:
   'Request body doesn\'t fulfill schema, see details in `fields`' }`

Comment: what is the machine_id field? Not sure where to get that.

Comment: I get this: {"code":"INVALID_BODY","fields":[{"code":"INVALID_BODY","message":"invalid character 'o' looking for beginning of value","path":"records"}],"message":"Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`"}